# How to copy a Graph object in Snap.py?

Tags: python, snappy

I try to use copy.deepcopy(graph) but got an error:

my code:

```
new_graph = TNEANet.New()
....
# some define for new_graph
....
copy_graph = copy.deepcopy(new_graph)
```

Execution error:

```
TypeError: object.__new__(SwigPyObject) is not safe, use SwigPyObject.__new__()
```

Also I found the API has a definition [API Document](http://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/doc/reference/graphs.html#tneanet). So I tried to use `TNEANet(Graph)` for that task:

```
new_graph = TNEANet.New()
....
# some define for new_graph
....
copy_graph = TNEANet(new_graph)
```

Execution error:

```
TypeError: in method 'new_TNEANet', argument 1 of type 'TSIn &'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ConvertGraph](https://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/doc/reference/ConvertGraph.html) method for copying a graph. Just use the same type of the graph as targeted type:

```
graph = snap.TNEANet.New()

graph.AddNode(1)
graph.AddNode(2)
graph.AddEdge(1,2)

copy_graph = snap.ConvertGraph(type(graph), graph)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

The best thing to do is to **copy the nodes, edges, and attributes yourself**. I found out that dumping to a file and reloading is also working quite well, although it won't copy your attributes if you are working with a `PNEANet`. Here is a handy function I used to copy the graphs (faster than iterating):

```
def copy_graph(graph):
    tmpfile = '.copy.bin'

    # Saving to tmp file
    FOut = snap.TFOut(tmpfile)
    graph.Save(FOut)
    FOut.Flush()

    # Loading to new graph
    FIn = snap.TFIn(tmpfile)
    graphtype = type(graph)
    new_graph = graphtype.New()
    new_graph = new_graph.Load(FIn)

    return new_graph
```

**Long answer**

There is a method to perform a deep copy your graph:

```
import snap
new_graph = snap.TNEANet.New()
....
# some define for new_graph
....
copy_graph = snap.TNEANet(new_graph())
```

(This works for any type of graph)
The problem is that it returns a `snap.TNEANet` when we need a `snap.PNEANet`. The latter is just a pointer to the former in the C++ implementation, but we have no way to get create this pointer in Python. As a result, `copy_graph` will have less functionalities than `new_graph`.

**Explainations**:

SNAP is using a proxy representation for python that somehow complicates the deep copy process. The copy constructor is expecting the non-proxy type, and you are giving it the python proxy type.
A `TypeError` is raised displaying the signature of the first constructor with 1 argument that it knows (which is completely irrelevant here).

To solve this, we need to give the constructor the underlying C++ type which is obtained by using the `self.__call__()` method.

But because of the C++ (bad?) implementation, `snap.TNEANet(new_graph())` outputs a `snap.TNEANet`. That means that the output of this function will be a non proxy type. As a result it won't work with most SNAP functionalities...